# List of strings in python issue

Tags: python

I have a weird problem, so basically when I write this:

```
def deletex():
    s= "The quick red fox jumped over the lazy dog."
    t= s.split()
    for x in t:
            t.remove(x)

    return t
print deletex()
```

So I don't get nearly what I expected, it removes every other word instead of every single one.

Why?

I can get around it with appending to a different list, but I want it to work this way too, since lists are *supposed* to be mutable. Also I noticed when I try to do x.capitalize() it doesn't work without appending to an empty list.

Comment: you should not be modifying an iterator while iterating through it.

Comment: Also, just for future, `list.clear()` will delete everything in the list.  No need for a multi-line function.